# Feature stroke is not updated

Tags: openlayers, features

I'm changing the stroke color of my features when they are selected like follows:

```
  var select = new Select({
    condition: click
  });
  select.on('select', function (e) {
    e.selected.forEach(function (feature) {
      feature.getStyle().getStroke().setColor([r, g, b, 1]);
    });
  });
```

It is working but when the map is translated, the deselected feature doesn't change its stroke.

I tried to use also the e.deselected property to set the default stroke color but it didn't work

Comment: Features have separate styles when selected and not selected.  You should use the style option in ol.interaction.Select to set the style for selected features.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike suggested you should be using [select interaction](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Select.html)'s style option unless you have some reason not to.

```
var select = new Select({
    condition: click,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [255,0,0,1],
        })
    })
});
```